# UPDATE stmt conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__"The conflict occurred in database ""table "", col 'courseid'The stmt has been terminated

Tags: asp.net

C# code:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_updatecourse", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseid",TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title",TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@credits",TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departmentid", TextBox4.Text);
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

while i am executing this i am getting error like

```
The UPDATE statement conflict with    the REFERENCE constraint
"FK__courseins__cours__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in database
"m", table "dbo.courseinstructor", column 'courseid'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

in the executenonquery what i have to do

Comment: you're trying to violate a foreign key dependency. we can't help you fix that, other than tell you that your new record must satisfy all foreign key constraints on the table, which means it needs matching records in all FK-related tables.

Comment: courseid col getting conflict

Answer (score 0):

You have a Foreign Key dependency conflict, which means that you have a Foreign Key between two tables and you're trying to insert a key value that has no associated row in the other table.

In your example, it looks like the procedure you're calling (`proc_updatecourse`) is updating a row in the `dbo.courseinstructor` table, but it is trying to change the value of the `courseid` column to something that does not exist in the referenced table.  You can only use the values in the referenced table (might be `course` or something like that, from your example).

It may be that the `TextBox1.Text` is not returning what you think it is.

Comment: having same col in two tables

Comment: The column names don't matter - the values do. The definition of the foreign key between the tables will show you which column it depends on. Those are the only valid values you will be allowed to use. Really, this is very basic database stuff you could find out in 2 minutes. It's not a C# issue, it's a database issue.